# White MacBook ca 2009/2010 slower and vibrating

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro

I have scoured the net for some advice on a recent issue with my MacBook.
It was for several years fast and silent but now the browser (fx 18.0.2) is perceptibly slower and there is a hum where I touch the keyboard which is not the fan - so I'm guessing hard-disk.

Core-2 duo 2GB ram

[image]

I have repaired permissions (which btw broke iPhoto and Preview so I had to reinstall them) AND verified the hard-disk.

1. Is it advisable to ignore the hum as a suspension issue from dried out rubber and add a folded napkin between the HD and the battery as some suggested?
2. is it worth it to add some RAM (I think I know the answer ;)
3. **The real question**: is it worth getting a new SSD and get rid of any moving parts?

My biggest fear is getting a new mac for some 1500 usd to find that it is NOT as silent as this used to be

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an Apple Hardware Test disc? You could also try verifying the hard disk in Disk Utility.

Comment: I do not have a hardware test disc but I DID verify (updated question)